# JpaRepository.save(entity) not working. SQLError 0, SQLState: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a POST endpoint on Java Spring with JPA, Lombok and Hibernate.

I'll show you the code i have on the controller, the entity, the service and a screenshot of the error I have to see if you can help me.

Sorry for the spanish on the code, it's for college.

The controller with the POST request:

```java
 @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> iniciarAlquiler(@RequestBody AlquilerRequest aRequest) {
        try {
            val alquiler = alquilerService.iniciarAlquiler(aRequest.getClienteId(), aRequest.getEstacionId());
            System.out.println(alquiler);
            return ResponseHandler.success(AlquilerResponse.from(alquiler));

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseHandler.badRequest(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseHandler.internalError();
        }
    }
```

The entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALQUILERES")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Alquiler {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ESTACION_DEVOLUCION")
    private int estacionDevolucion;

    @Column(name = "ESTACION_RETIRO")
    private int estacionRetiro;

    @Column(name = "ESTADO")
    private int estado;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_HORA_DEVOLUCION")
    private LocalDateTime horaDevolucion;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_HORA_RETIRO")
    private LocalDateTime horaRetiro;

    @Column(name = "ID_CLIENTE")
    private long idCliente;

    @Column(name = "MONTO")
    private double monto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TARIFA")
    private Tarifa tarifa;
```

The service (note: definirTarifa works ok. It finds another entity):

```java
@Override
    public Alquiler iniciarAlquiler(int idCliente, int estacionRetiroId) {

        val estado = 1;

        LocalDateTime fechaHoraRetiro = LocalDateTime.now();
        val tarifa = definirTarifa(fechaHoraRetiro);

        val newAlquiler = new Alquiler();
        newAlquiler.setEstado(estado);
        newAlquiler.setEstacionRetiro(estacionRetiroId);
        //newAlquiler.setHoraRetiro(fechaHoraRetiro);
        newAlquiler.setIdCliente(idCliente);
        newAlquiler.setTarifa(tarifa);

        return alquileresRepository.save(newAlquiler);
    }
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLt7B.png)
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLkff.png)

I'm new to programming in general, in fact this is my first StackOverflow question. The class in which im learning this is not good, and I had to learn everything on my own basically. I barely know what i'm doing. If you could also redirect me to some good resources for learning this or solving issues on my own i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share your table creation query to check if there is some typo error while creating this entity and also your database connection, properties or yml file it'll be helpful

Comment: @Daksharajkamal

The database was given to me by the teacher, so i don't have the table creation query.
Properties:

```spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:bicicletas.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC


spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8 and therefore doesn’t support the new Date and Time API.
So check the  columns like horaDevolucion and horaRetiro data type and check SQLite support that data type.

**Two options**

1. Update to JPA 2.2 and hibernate 5 support date and time API
2. Convert LocalDateTime to Timestamp using @Converter. [Refer this link for the sample](https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)

Comment: [It looks like I have all dependencies up to date.](https://prnt.sc/FjApR9oDOMCT)   I'll try the conversion